# how to load language file in application (ios swift)

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization, swift2

i am making application in swift i want to make in two language. 
and i allready create two language file. but now i want to put two button on starting of application and if user click button 1 it will load english language and if user click button 2 it will load other language so how can i load language file.

allready tried : allready created two language file only want to know how to load them manually

Comment: What do you mean by "language file"? Is it the `.strings` file with the translations?

Comment: https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager

Comment: yes it is .string file@Arc676

Answer (score 0):

You can do that yourself. Only the user can change the language he use in his device setting.

Why do you thing a user want to use your application in a different language he use for his device ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked using Swift 2.2 on iOS 9:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["fr"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Then you can use `NSLocalizedString` normally, and the system language will be overridden by what was set at `["fr"]` (French in this case).  An app restart is required however for changes to take effect.

Source: [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27676623/1420793)