# Force localization in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I need to change the language of the app from English to Arabic and vice versa programatically from the app. I use xib files, not story boards.
With lot of googling, I could force load the localisation strings. But the xibs do not reload to reflect the right to left allignment of Arabic language.
Kindly help.

Edit:
Or is there a way to reload the xibs? Or even restart the app programatically?

Comment: Are you trying to do it dynamically without relaunching the app or after changing and relaunching the app? What are your typical methods used to load the xib files?

Comment: what do you mean by force lad the localisation strings ?

Comment: @PradeepK Yes. I have a settings tab, and there I need to give an option to change the language in a tableview. Once that language selection is done, the app needs to reflect the changes. I have no issues in relaunching the app internally too.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri  Force loading the localisation strings from within the app. Not by the usual way of changing the phone language.

Comment: How did you try to check localisation strings without changing the device language ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri  I tried a method mentioned in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That helps to get the respective strings. But since it is Arabic, I need to change to right to left alignment of objects in xib.

Comment: are you trying in device or simulator?

Comment: you need to refresh the outlets one-by-one.

Comment: @techloverr I have tried on device and simulator. No luck.

Comment: @holex yes, but how? Any tutorials? Samples?

Comment: @dinny, imagination. you don't need any tutorial for that simple tasks.

Comment: Please don't do this. This will never work 100% and also provides a very confusing user experience. Users expect their apps to follow the system language, and they certainly don't expect every single one of their apps to have a separate language selector with tons of options.

Comment: @wakachamo Yes, but these days there are lot of apps in the store that allows to change the language on the fly. My client requirement demands the same.

Comment: @holex imagination does not work :(

Comment: Since you're using XIBs, you can just use `[NSBundle -pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:]` and load the NIB directly by hand. See duplicate question. It does require redesigning part of your app, but since you're already working with XIBs, it's probably not too massive. See also the NSUserDefaults option if you're willing to restart the app.