# Change app's language without restart app

Tags: ios, objective-c, internationalization

I need to change my app language without restart app, I try this solution :

1. for English and

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

2. For french

   `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english

Comment: try this man

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/20257557#20257557

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

Comment: Thank @RicardoAlves, I checked this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want to look at [this(Hodor)](https://github.com/Aufree/Hodor) i have not used it but it might work for you.

It claims that you can change app language without restating your app like wechat(i dont know much about wechat).