# Change language inside app using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I need to change my app language tapping a button in my app. I've used `NSLocalizedStrings` all around the app View Controllers and I already have `Localizable.strings` file created with the translations inside.

What code should I use to change the language without restarting my app?

I've tried this but it's not working.

```
@IBAction func changeToSpanish(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set("es", forKey: "i18n_language")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: In general, you should not make your app's language different than the system setting.

Comment: It's a University app with 3 languages one of them regional. It's necessary to allow the user to change app language inside of the app.

Comment: You're setting the key in user defaults? How are you reading this key and applying it.

Comment: I'm setting the key using the function above but I don't know how to read the key.

Comment: You can outsource the problem to a third party framework, or at least check their implementation for inspiration if you want. There are several, here is the first one coming on Google : https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)