# Localization translations do not update / get deleted

Tags: swift, localization

I am currently developing an application, and tried to work with Localization. I enabled German language as a localizable language and completed the strings file. Afterwards I wanted to make it only English again, and disabled the German language in the Localization options and storyboards, but it is still changing to German language while using it on a German device.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make it only English again, or know if I might have missed something?

Comment: I would refer you to this post for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985614/how-can-i-change-locale-programmatically-with-swift/31744226#31744226

Comment: please check link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447630/localization-in-swift-restrict-app-to-one-language-even-if-the-app-has-more-la/46461580#46461580