# Localization in arabic changes direction

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Hello In my application i am using this pod https://github.com/Abedalkareem/LanguageManager-iOS and i have commented all code which change the direction of the Views, but when i change language from english to arabic it changes the direction of text when i reopen the app it change direction from left to right and when i select english again everything is ok, i want to disable , i don't want to do anything when language change.

this is code of my language man

```
ager
//
//  LanguageManger.swift
//
//  Created by abedalkareem omreyh on 10/23/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 abedlkareem omreyh. All rights reserved.
//  GitHub: https://github.com/Abedalkareem/LanguageManger-iOS
//

import UIKit

class LanguageManger {

    static let shared: LanguageManger = LanguageManger()


    /// Returns the currnet language
    var currentLanguage: Languages {
        get {

            guard let currentLang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedLanguage")
                else {
                    fatalError("Did you set the default language for the app ?")
            }
            return Languages(rawValue: currentLang)!
        }
        set {
            print("raw value\(newValue.rawValue)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "selectedLanguage")
        }
    }

    /// Returns the default language that the app will run first time
    var defaultLanguage: Languages {
        get {

            guard let defaultLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "defaultLanguage") else {
                fatalError("Did you set the default language for the app ?")
            }
            return Languages(rawValue: defaultLanguage)!
        }
        set {

            // swizzle the awakeFromNib from nib and localize the text in the new awakeFromNib
            UIView.localize()

            let defaultLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "defaultLanguage")
            guard defaultLanguage == nil else {
                return
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "defaultLanguage")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "selectedLanguage")
            setLanguage(language: newValue)
        }
    }


    // Returns the diriction of the language
        var isRightToLeft: Bool {
            get {
                let lang = currentLanguage.rawValue
                return lang.contains("s") || lang.contains("he") || lang.contains("ur") || lang.contains("fa")
            }
        }

    /// Returns the app locale for use it in dates and currency
    var appLocale: Locale {
        get {
            return Locale(identifier: currentLanguage.rawValue)
        }
    }

    ///
    /// Set the current language for the app
    ///
    /// - parameter language: The language that you need from the app to run with
    ///
    func setLanguage(language: Languages) {

      //   change the dircation of the views
//        let semanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttribute = language == .ar ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceRightToLeft
//                UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semanticContentAttribute
//                UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semanticContentAttribute
//                UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semanticContentAttribute
//                UITextView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = semanticContentAttribute

        // change app language
        UserDefaults.standard.set([language.rawValue], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        // set current language
        currentLanguage = language
        print("---curent langugae from lanagugae maneger \(currentLanguage)")
    }
}

enum Languages:String {
    case ar,en,nl,ja,ko,vi,ru,sv,fr,es,pt,it,de,da,fi,nb,tr,el,id,ms,th,hi,hu,pl,cs,sk,uk,hr,ca,ro,he
    case enGB = "en-GB"
    case enAU = "en-AU"
    case enCA = "en-CA"
    case enIN = "en-IN"
    case frCA = "fr-CA"
    case esMX = "es-MX"
    case ptBR = "pt-BR"
    case zhHans = "zh-Hans"
    case zhHant = "zh-Hant"
    case zhHK = "zh-HK"
}


// MARK: Swizzling
extension UIView {
    static func localize() {

        let orginalSelector = #selector(awakeFromNib)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzledAwakeFromNib)

        let orginalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, orginalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, orginalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod!))

        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(orginalMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(orginalMethod!))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(orginalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
        }

    }

    @objc func swizzledAwakeFromNib() {
        swizzledAwakeFromNib()

        switch self {
        case let txtf as UITextField:
            txtf.text = txtf.text?.localiz()
        case let lbl as UILabel:
            lbl.text = lbl.text?.localiz()
        case let btn as UIButton:
            btn.setTitle(btn.title(for: .normal)?.localiz(), for: .normal)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


// MARK: String extension
extension String {


    /// Localize the current string to the selected language

    /// - returns: The localized string
    ///
    func localiz() -> String {
        guard let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: LanguageManger.shared.currentLanguage.rawValue, ofType: "lproj") else {
            return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
        }

        let langBundle = Bundle(path: bundle)
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: langBundle!, comment: "")
    }

}

// MARK: UIApplication extension
extension UIApplication {
    // Get top view controller
    static var topViewController:UIViewController? {
        get{
            if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
                while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                    topController = presentedViewController
                }
                return topController
            }else{
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i am doing this after change language but happens nothing

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
               UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
                    UITextView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
                   UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

[In Arabic langauge text shows in right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1lPe.jpg)

Comment: Please see below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447630/localization-in-swift-restrict-app-to-one-language-even-if-the-app-has-more-la

Answer (score 0):

UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight

Comment: If you didn`t done this the system will automatically assign this value by semantic of your locale

Comment: iam doing like this when i change into arabic but nothing happens check my edited question with image

Comment: Do this in appdelegate in didfinishlaunching

Comment: If you do this in moment when view already created you should use clutches like remove this view from superview and add again.

Maybe view.layoutSubviews() will help you

Comment: i don't understand its okay when i change arabic in app , but it change direction when i reopen app

Comment: And it doesn`t work? Try to set semantic in storyboard then. For each view. It can be done with interface builder.

Comment: bro there are more then 100 views

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any pod or any external library for Localizing the app.
There are few steps that you need to do.

First Create string file for localization.

Add Language in you project setting.

Now in the string file, file navigate enable localization.

Select all the languages that you need to localize.

Now add all the string that you want to change in language.

Download all the language in you phone or simulator, for eg for Arabic download arabic language in the phone or simulator.

Now on click of language change button navigate user to the setting.
Where user will get preferred language option.

Once user selects any language for eg arabic the system automatically restart the app and you will see all the views and all the text will shifted to RTL.

I would suggest go through the apple documentation for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `view.contentMode = .right` , this will force the content no matter what language it is, as when it's in Arabic it changes to left.

Comment: Instance member 'contentMode' cannot be used on type 'UIView'