# Restart required in iPhone Application on changing Language

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization

When we changed the language on the fly in iPhone application, some framework did not change its language until we restart application properly such as UIImagePickerController . Is there a way to change the language of those framework without restarting application. if not how we can reload or restart whole application.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language

Comment: Internal libraries are not localized on language change such as UIKit. Need to restart the app for this. Any thing else that you could suggest?

Comment: @UmairAli Do you use pods?

Comment: Yes, I used pod for third party.