# Sets of English Strings combined with Localization that supports UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, nslocalizedstring

I have an app that is used to track/manage livestock. It currently supports one species, Sheep. We want to begin supporting multiple different species, like Goats, and Cattle. My first thought was to create something similar to `NSLocalizedString(text, comment)` like `SpeciesString(text, species, comment)` which would take the English string and the species name and translate the Sheep term `Ram` to the Cattle term `Bull`. And internal to that, I could use `NSLocalizedString()` to then further translate that to the proper language so that in the future I could support multiple languages as well.

I see that I can pass a `tableName` to `NSLocalizedString()` so that it will use a different file other than `Localizeable.strings` and that would allow me to programmatically pull values from a Spanish language file that is focused on Cattle instead of Sheep (something like `Localizeable-sheep.strings` and `Localizeable-cattle.strings`), but that won't help me with all of the text that is in the storyboard.

I know that there is built-in support for localization with the storyboard, but the problem I'm having is that when the text comes to my code, for example in `viewDidLoad`, it will already have been translated to the other language, for example Spanish. I would prefer to find a way to make the text  in my views already have the right Language+Species combination by the time it gets to my code. But even if I did rely on programmatically swapping out the strings to use the right Species, the English will already been changed to Spanish and I'll get `Carnero` instead of `Ram` and if I try to pass that through to my `SpeciesString()` it won't match my underlying data, because my underlying data is keying off of the English version of the text.

Is there a way to create a custom language? I've seen this [code that is used to change the localization language on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746920/416631), and it works for swapping between `en` and `es`, but I can't create my own fake languages like `en-sheep` and `es-sheep`.

Is there either:

a) a way to create my own custom language so that the localization system will just pick my correct Language+Species combination?

or

b) a way to tell the Storyboard which table name/filename to pull strings from? So that instead of just having a strings file for my `Main.storyboard` be called `es.lproj/Main.strings` but I could instead have
`es.lproj/Main-sheep.strings` and `es.lproj/Main-cattle.strings`?

Answer (score 0):

I think my inability to get my "custom language" to work was just an accidental oversight. I created an `es-sheep.lproj/Main.strings` and used [the other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920) to programmatically set my language to `es-sheep` and it didn't seem to work...

... but it turned out that I had created those directories and files, but forgotten to add them to the project. Once I manually added them to the project, it started working and I was able to use my custom localizations.